# Summing values across two rows by a grouping variable and then divide by another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

For some bouts I have two measures for the variable distance. I would like to sum the distances per bout e.g. bout 1n would be 345+402=747 and then divide it by the No.tr column for that bout which for bout 1n is 2 so that I get an average per bout.

| Bouts | No.tr | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1n | 2 | 345 |
| 1n | 2 | 402 |
| 2 | 2 | 254 |
| 2 | 2 | 320 |
| 2n | 2 | 230 |
| 2n | 2 | 150 |
| 3 | 1 | 200 |

Comment: So `df %>% group_by(Boutse) %>% summarise(res = mean(Distance))`?

Comment: Worked like a charm - so simple. Very grateful, thank you.